# Jquery Need Help - Changing content when clicking on a link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need help.  I'm trying to get a link to change the displayed answer when you click on the link.  I want it to toggle back and forth each time you click on it.  I've been playing around with multiple items but nothing seems to work yet.  I've commented out some notes to help sort out what I want to do.  Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE></TITLE>
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


function flipSwitch(){
document.getElementById('first').style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('second').style.display = 'block';
    //get the first div into this variable
    //var firstDiv = document.getElementById('first');
    firstDiv.style

    //change it's style/display properties from none to block.  Is it visible now when you click the link?
    //firstDiv.
}

</script>
</HEAD>


<BODY>

<div id="home">
<A HREF="javascript:flipSwitch()">Let's see if we can get this to work?</A>
</div>

<div id="first" style="DISPLAY: none;">This is a test...</div>

<div id="second" style="DISPLAY: none;">of the emergency broadcast system</div>

</BODY>
```

Comment: `<a href="#" onclick="flipSwitch()">Let's see if we can get this to work?</a>`

Answer (score 0):

It's good practice to move javascript out of your HTML. 
Here is an example of toggling the CSS Display property in javascript.

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/LdPfS/

```
var link = document.querySelector("#home > a")

link.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    var firstDiv = document.getElementById('first'),
        secondDiv = document.getElementById('second'),
        toggle = firstDiv.style.display === "none" ? "block" : "none"

        /* toggle = firstDiv.style.display === "none" ? "block" : "none"
         * Read as
         * if ( firstDiv.style.display === "none" ) {
         *     toggle = "block"
         * else {
         *     toggle = "none"
         * }
         */

    firstDiv.style.display = toggle
    secondDiv.style.display = toggle
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the all caps html is weird but for the sake of making this quick, I'll copy/paste your code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE></TITLE>
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function flipSwitch(){
        // first and foremost, you're using jQuery so let's use jquery
        if ($('#first').is(':hidden')) {
          $('#first').show();
          $('#second').hide();
        } else {
          $('#first').hide();
          $('#second').show();
        }
    }

    // next, let's get your javascript OUT of the html
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // when the document has loaded, attach our function as a
        // click handler to the link
        $('#my_switch').on('click', flipSwitch);
    });

</script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

    <div id="home">
        <a id="my_switch">Let's see if we can get this to work?</a>
    </div>

    <div id="first" style="DISPLAY: none;">This is a test...</div>
    <div id="second" style="DISPLAY: none;">of the emergency broadcast system</div>

</BODY>
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to MBottens, but with some simple JQuery:

```
$('#home > a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    $('#first').toggle();
    $('#second').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this logic. Take a global variable and set its value to 1.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var countClick=1;

  function flipSwitch(){
   if(countClick%2==0){
  document.getElementById('first').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('second').style.display = 'none';
  }
  else{
   document.getElementById('first').style.display = 'none';
   document.getElementById('second').style.display = 'block';

  }
 countClick++;
  }

 </script>
```

Also please change your html with the following html:

```
<body>

<div id="home">
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="flipSwitch()">Let's see if we can get this to work?</a>
</div>

 <div id="first" style="display: none;">This is a test...</div>

 <div id="second" style="display: none;">of the emergency broadcast system</div>

</body>
```